# Ants tending bugs on Almond tree

Tags: ants, parasites, almond

We are the in south of France .. our almond tree has (large) ants tending groups of small bugs. They are always in clusters, on the underside of main branches. Any ideas of how to eradicate them please? (See photos … normal dinner knife serations to give scale) - thanks

[image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classic ants tending aphids. The ants get liquid food from the aphids so protect them. Malathion is a common , short life insecticide used on food plants in the US. Also Sevin.

Comment: There's really no need to use any insecticide. Ants & aphids love [garden nasturtium](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/57848/ants-on-trees-ok-or-bad/57864#57864).

Comment: Right ! Sevin  ( wetable  powder ) works well also.